# Drainage rock/backfill for retaining wall

Tags: walls

I'm building a retaining wall and when I told them to deliver 3/4" gravel, I forgot to tell them crushed gravel. So now I have 13 yards of gravel, which is kind of rounded for the backfill, will I be okay with this rock? I've already started to backfill the retaining wall. [image]

Comment: I'm no expert on this, so take this comment with a few grains of salt! I think you're fine. Rounded rock, also sometimes referred to as "drain rock" will be helpful in draining the wall. You could carry on with crushed rock higher up, but it might be hard to compress with the drain rock underneath...not sure.  If you really want it solid maybe mix some crushed in the first layer of drain rock.  To  compress use a jumping jack tamping tool every 6" of lift to compress till you reach the top of your fill.   Again, I'm no expert on this, this is only a comment, hopefully others will weigh in.

Comment: Afaik you want "sharp" crushed rock when you plan to compact it so that it "grips" together to make the compacted mix stronger, and less likely to shift under weight. For drainage behind a retaining wall you don't need that, since the wall is holding it all up.

Comment: you can add and tamp some sand on the top if you want to aid later compaction by reducing shifting. @brhans fun fact: sharp edges in base material chip during shipping and install into _fines_ which work their way into corners and edges to produce what the pros call an uncompressible _matrix_. DOT-graded base, which goes under highways, comes with a particular + regulated mixture of sieve sizes to maximize this effect, which drive up cost but guarantees performance...

Comment: While I agree that you can use pebble gravel in this situation, you are eventually going to clog that gravel since you don't have a barrier (filter fabric) between your earth behind and your drainage layer.

Comment: Clogging would be what the OP is after, wouldn't it, @Huesmann? After all, if he'd gotten the proper stuff in the first place, it would have included the fines which would have helped to pack it down and "clogged" it up anyway, right? He's not really after drainage here, but back fill...

Comment: @FreeMan no. Clogging is *not* what you want.  Clogging will hold water behind the wall, increasing hydrostatic pressure, leading to premature failure of the wall.

Comment: I called 3 different local block places and they said I don't need filter fabric between the soil and gravel because there is sandy soil, if it was clay or other soil then you would use filter fabric, but they said 95% of ppl here in NM don't use the filter fabric